# How big should the hydraulic press's connecting cylinder be?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [britannica.com](https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/06/156806-004-E83D05DA.jpg))</sub>
I'm trying to build a simple hydraulic press out of water bottles. I have the bottles of different width, but I don't know what width the connecting cylinder (between big and small cylinders) should be.
Does the connecting cylinder's width matter? If it does, should it be close to either cylinder's width, or be in between of the two, or anything like that? 
Also, does the connecting cylinder's length or shape matter? If they do, what should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size and shape of the connecting tube won't make any difference to the *static* pressure on each side of the press.

While you are *moving* the pistons, you are pumping liquid through the connecting tube. If you reduce the cross section area of the tube, the flow velocity will have to increase, or the pistons will have to move slower. As the flow velocity increases, it will take more pressure difference *between the ends of the connector* to push the liquid through it.

The pressure drop is proportional to the length $l$ of the connector, but the diameter has a bigger effect, because the pressure drop is roughly proportional to $lv^2/d$ where $v$ is the velocity and $d$ is the diameter. For a fixed speed of movement of the pistons, you have a fixed flow rate (volume/second) in the connector, and the pressure drop is roughly proportional to $l/d^5$ because $v$ increases as $d$ decreases.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation for more detail, or use a calculator like http://www.pressure-drop.com/Online-Calculator/

Comment: By "cross section area", do you mean the connecting cylinder? Also, does the connecting cylinder's position matter? For example, can I attach it near the bottom of one cylinder but about 1/3 from the bottom on another?